# How is the memory allocation done for variables in scripting languages?

Tags: javascript, memory-management, scripting, variables

For example, in javascript

I can say

```
var x = 5;
```

Later I can do

```
x = 'a';
```

and then

```
x = "hello";
```

So, how is memory allocated for the variables? As it is, all variables have a common type 'var' and values of variables can change at run-time as seen above. Isn't it a difficult task to allocate and manage memory for these variables? Exactly, how is it done?

Comment: See also this stack overflow [How variables are allocated memory in Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2800463/how-variables-are-allocated-memory-in-javascript) especially a comment that contains a link to this dissertation [Three Implementation Models for Scheme](http://www.cs.unm.edu/~williams/cs491/three-imp.pdf) by R. Kent Dybvig.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python uses a technique called [reference counting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_counting), which basically puts a counter in the value. Each time a reference to a value is created, the counter is incremented. When a reference to the value is lost (for instance when you assign a new value to 'x'), the value is decremented. When the counter reaches zero, that means that no reference to the value exists, and it can be deallocated. This is a simplified explanation, but that's at least the basics.

Comment: so what will x be treated as? when i say x=5, then will it be treated as an int or a string during allocation? and where will the type information be stored?

Comment: How the variable is allocated and the type information is stored will be implementation specific. If you want to see how one implementation does it, you can download Rhino: JavaScript for Java http://www.mozilla.org/rhino/.

Comment: This is only true in CPython and also ignores garbage collection. You should fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, *those* variables are references to immutable strings which are allocated at compile time.

Of course it depends on the VM, but in general, I think, most C-based scripting languages allocate a large block of memory, expanding it as necessary and do their own allocation within that, rarely if ever giving anything back to the O/S.  Especially in a lexically scoped language, which almost all of them are, variables are all allocated dynamically within this block, not on anything analogous to a C stack, and they are freed with either reference counting or with a garbage collector.

If your scripting language is running on the JVM, or .NET, or something like it (Parrot?), creating a variable is merely the creation of something like a Java object.  Some time after there are no more references to the object, the garbage collector will reclaim the memory.

Comment: Except that the VM may do escape analysis and sometimes allocate objects on the stack anyway.