# How can JS handle different datatypes for the same variable?

Tags: javascript, variables, web, memory, runtime

I know that Javascript is a **dynamic language**, and its way of dealing with the data types and the runtime is different than the other languages.

In the below example:

```js
var x = 5;
document.writeln(x + ", " + typeof(x)); //output: 5, number

x = "Hello";
document.writeln(x + ", " + typeof(x)); //ouput: Hello, string
```

When I change the value of `x`, it works well without any problem. I'm confused because I know that, when `x` is of type **number**, it has a different memory size than when it is of type **string** and in the end, they're the same variable. 
I would like to know how it works? How `x=5` and `x="Hello"` can be stored in memory and they have different data types with different sizes?

### **UPDATE**

I mean, when `x` is **number**, it stores for example 4 bytes in the memory, and when I make the `x` of type **string**, it will store for example 8 bytes. How does this happen? Will the memory extend the size of x to be bigger? or Will it remove the previous space from the memory and create another one? or Is there a different way?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Addition might help and https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ecmascript-language-expressions.html#sec-addition-operator-plus

Comment: The JavaScript Engine will simply free the old memory and reserve new memory when the data type changes. I'm not sure what you're asking exactly? It's not magic, just a possible way of implementing a programming language. If somebody gave you a three page explantion of how it works, would you really be interested in that? I for one couldn't care less.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript - Which data is stored in "var" and how its content/storage is changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44460216/javascript-which-data-is-stored-in-var-and-how-its-content-storage-is-change)

Comment: I mean, when `x` is **number**, it stores for example 4 bytes in the memory, and when I make the `x` of type **string**, it will store for example 8 bytes. How does this happen? Will the memory extend the size of x to be bigger? Or will it remove the previous space from the memory and create another one?

Comment: That will depend on the JavaScript engine. https://v8.dev/docs

Answer (score 0):

I think you are partially right. For understanding this you need to know about (Primitive and reference ) type in javascript.  The variable x is primitive in javascript. On the other hand Objects, functions, arrays are reference types. When we declare a primitive type in javascript it allocates space in memory. when we call it, it delivers the value with the specific memory space. So when we reassign it will not erase the previous space and but relocate the new value to another space. When for reference type this is different.

You can verify my answer to doing this example:

var x=10;
console.log(x)

x= "Hello"
console.log(x)

or you can check the mdn docs for premitive type.