# How to create an object inside forEach without declaring it outside?

Tags: javascript

I wonder how to create an object inside the foreach? Without posting here all my code, in my case, I cannot declare the object outside of the foreach (using react and doing that insight my render function which leads to weird results). How can I do that? Thanks!

```
    var list;
    this.state.resp.forEach(function(e) {
       list[e.OriginLocation.AirportCode] = e.OriginLocation.CityName;
    });
```

Comment: Well, you can't declare it inside the forEach unless you want to re-declare it every iteration. Can you assign to a new variable?

Answer (score 2):

You can use another array function such as `reduce` like:

```
this.state.resp.reduce(function(list, e) {
   list[e.OriginLocation.AirportCode] = e.OriginLocation.CityName;
   return list;
}, {});
```

`reduce` will then return the accumulated list which you can use or return directly (without assigning it to a variable if you want).

Answer (score 1):

You *can* create an object inside the `forEach`:

```
whatever.forEach(function(e) {
   var list[e.OriginLocation.AirportCode] = e.OriginLocation.CityName; 
});
```

**But** you will lose the reference (named `list`) to your object when the `forEach` completes. References are stored on the call stack (which will be lost when the call to `forEach` returns) and the object itself is stored on the heap.

The object will still exist in memory, but you won't have a reference to it.

Useful reading:

http://cslibrary.stanford.edu/102/PointersAndMemory.pdf

[What and where are the stack and heap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79923/what-and-where-are-the-stack-and-heap)

[How variables are allocated memory in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2800463/how-variables-are-allocated-memory-in-javascript)